# Proper toolbar styling

Tags: android, toolbar

I would like to avoid applying a style to the toolbars in all layouts, so I have a style I created for it:

```
<style name="DarkToolbar" >
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
</style>
```

And I added it to my theme as follows:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:toolbarStyle">@style/DarkToolbar</item>
</style>
```

This is the resulting toolbar:
[image: toolbar with style applied in theme]

As you can see, the title and subtitle have the wrong formatting. If I remove the style from the theme and apply it directly to the toolbar in the layout, I get the following result instead:

[image]

Both images use the same style. One is applied through the app theme with

```
<item name="android:toolbarStyle">@style/DarkToolbar</item>
```

and the second one is applied directly to the toolbar with

```
style="@style/DarkToolbar"
```

Does anyone know the reason for the difference?
Also, does anyone know why the

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```

Are not being applied?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add `parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar"` to your toolbar style. It is default style for toolbar.

For example:

```
<style name="DarkToolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hi @princeparadoxes. Thanks, but I've already tried that. It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with

< item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar< /item>

in your style

I personally find styling toolbar text quite complicated, so mostly end up with my own TextView. How about using your own TextView inside toolbar. It would be easy, though a bit lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting parent as no action bar in your theme, as this will give you the run time exception and null point exception as there is no action bar or tool bar to set the title/sub-title. Try adding parent in your theme with toolbar or action bar likes this.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="DarkToolbar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:toolbarStyle">@style/DarkToolbar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but NoActionBar does not produce any exceptions. It simply prevents the system to auto include the toolbar. Anyway, choosing that parent still produces the same error.